# chasing , zone range

Tags: xna, geometry

here is an image show what I am gonna to do in my XNA game , I want to check if the player is inside zone range and if yes then attack the player , I tried to do this using checking ray but it's odd and give null results as player must be in front of enemy so he can be detected !

[image: enter code here]

hey every body , I want instead view angle for each enemy ( 3D dimension ):

[image]

Comment: There is no code.

Comment: `![enter comment here][1]` There is still no code but at least there is now a picture

Comment: What is "checking ray"? The problem is quite basic, it's just `distance(player, enemy) < range` where `distance(player, enemy) = sqrt((player.x-enemy.x)^2 + (player.y-enemy.y)^2)`. Also it's quite common to use squared distances to avoid the expensive `sqrt`.

Comment: In fact, since you're using XNA, you can just use the [Vector2.DistanceSquared Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.distancesquared.aspx).

Comment: thanks very very much sorry Jimmy , Cong :) I want it for 3D if you can with view angle instead of circle if you can

Answer (score 1):

When you use the XNA class Vector2 to represent the positions of the player and the enemies, you can use its method [Distance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.distance.aspx) to calculate the distance to another Vector2. Then you just have to check if this is smaller than the radius of the attack circle.

To calculate the distance between two points yourself, you can use the pythagorean theorem.

[image: distance calculation using pythagorean theorem]

```
// first get the horizontal and vertical distance.
double distanceX = player.x - enemy.x;
double distanceY = player.y - enemy.y;
// then calculate the length of the hypotenuse of the triangle they form
double dist = sqrt( (distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY) );
if (dist < enemy.attackZoneRadius) {
    enemy.attack(player);
}
```

This example is overly verbose for clarity. The distanceX and distanceY calculations can be put right into the calcualtion of dist:

To improve the performance, you can save the attack zone radius of the enemy already squared. You can then omit the call to sqrt (calculating square-roots is a quite expensive operation) or use the faster XNA Vector2 method [DistanceSquared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.distancesquared.aspx).

**Edit:** You didn't mention that you need this in 3-dimensional space. The XNA [Vector3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199673.aspx) class supports the methods Distance and DistanceSquared just like the 2d version. When you want to do this manually, [the pythagorean theorem still applies in 3d space](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTheorem3D/) (I think it applies to any number of  dimensions, but that's rather a question for math.stackexchange.com).

```
double distX = player.x - enemy.x;
double distY = player.y - enemy.y;    
double distZ = player.z - enemy.z;

double dist = sqrt( (distX * distX) + (distY * distY) + (distZ * distZ) );
```

Comment: Thanks Phulipp so much , but sorry I want this for 3D instead :) if you can pls

Comment: Philipp  it works , again I want it for 3D , then how to make enemy goes in the direction of player ?

Comment: @MohammadAhmed You should have mentioned that in your question, because the graphic implies two-dimensional space. I updated my answer.

Comment: thaaanks Philipp sorry :) I will mentioned it in the next time, I will post another question Ok later on , now for the first problem ( zone range ) , enemy moves in another direction , how to make it move toward me ?

2 : As the second picture shown , If I want to make view range ( 40 degree ) in front of each enemy for example , if in the view range then attak .

3 : Phillip , the last question is if I want to make enemy walk a little bit around his position ( from -10  to 10 ) for example , i.e as he is searching for some one , can you give me just steps ! thanks

Comment: @MohammadAhmed Now that's a whole bunch of new problems which all warrant entirely new questions.

Comment: Ok , I had post them :) , I hope you will say what you Know about them :)